# PHP: merge arrays without replacing data

Tags: php, arrays, replace, merge

Multiple arrays are given with the following structure (`print_r`):

```
Array
(
    [name] => Top Level
    [parent] => null
    [children] => Array
        (
            [name] => Level 2: A
            [parent] => Top Level
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Son of A
                    [parent] => Level 2: A
                )

        )

)

Array
(
    [name] => Top Level
    [parent] => null
    [children] => Array
        (
            [name] => Level 2: A
            [parent] => Top Level
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Daughter of A
                    [parent] => Level 2: A
                )

        )

)
```

Code to create arrays:

```
$array1 = array("name" => "Top Level", "parent" => "null", "children" => array("name" => "Level 2: A", "parent" => "Top Level", "children" => array("name" => "Son of A", "parent" => "Level 2: A")));
$array2 = array("name" => "Top Level", "parent" => "null", "children" => array("name" => "Level 2: A", "parent" => "Top Level", "children" => array("name" => "Daughter of A", "parent" => "Level 2: A")));
```

I want to merge them. I already tried `array_replace_recursive` and `array_merge_recursive`, but both gave me not my estimated result.
The desired result looks like following:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Top Level
    [parent] => null
    [children] => Array
        (
            [name] => Level 2: A
            [parent] => Top Level
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Son of A
                            [parent] => Level 2: A
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Daughter of A
                            [parent] => Level 2: A
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Any suggestions on how to realize this? Thank you!

Comment: Please show your code?

Comment: See edit, thank you!